# Having trouble why the split function does not work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split the salesData and it does want to `split()` by the comma after each object.

This is homework.I am trying to store it in a object map and do the calculation there.
For now I cant get past the `split` function failing me.

I have provided my code below to show as the end result what the most profitable department is.

```
var salesData = [
{department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
];

 var departmentMap = {};

function mostProfitableDepartment() {
 var departmentSplit = salesData.split(',');

  for (var i = 0; i < departmentSplit.length; i++) {
   var currentDep = departmentSplit[i]
  if (departmentMap[currentDep] === undefined) {
    departmentMap[currentDep] = 0;
  }
  departmentMap[currentDep] = departmentMap[currentDep]++
}
console.log(departmentMap);
}mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);
```

Comment: `salesData` is an array use `for` loop to iterate it. What do you want to `split(,)`

Comment: I want to gather all the department with the same name in the object map and add their sales to give me the most profitable department,

Comment: Since _This is homework_ You should do it, you will learn something

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as its a homework question. Not answering it will actually help OP.

Comment: No need to split, the data is an array not a string!

Comment: i did im trying. I just need clarification.

Comment: @Duvall912 : Satpal is right. When your var is between [ ], it's an array, not a String. So instead of using split, you can get each occurence  and assign them to departmentMap

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows by utilizing `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var salesData = [
{department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
{department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
{department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
],

      deptMap = salesData.reduce((p,c) => p[c.department] ? (p[c.department].push({sales: c.sales,
                                                                                    day: c.day}),p)
                                                         : (p[c.department] = [{sales: c.sales,
                                                                                  day: c.day}],p) ,{});
console.log(deptMap);
```

Comment: Can u clarify it in a much more simpler way please. @Redu

Comment: so you removed `ced` from reduced ?

Comment: @Duvall912 I am using a reduce function with an initial value which is an empty object `{}` and this initial value gets assigned to `p` argument in the callback of reduce wheras `c` is the current object in iteration. So if `p[c.department]` does not exist we create it and assign it an array with the first item like `(p[c.department] = [{sales: c.sales, day: c.day}],p)`. The last `p` after the comma operator is in fact like `return p` instruction. If the `p[c.department]` property has been created before we just add a new object like `(p[c.department].push({sales: c.sales, day: c.day}),p)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your iteration structure for the array, you already have. Then take the department property as actual department and for the count the sales property.

```js
var salesData = [{ department: 'hardware', sales: 4500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 1500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 5500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 7500, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 2505, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 1540, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 1500, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 8507, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 8009, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 12000, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 18007, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 6109, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 7005, day: 'Friday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 12006, day: 'Friday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 16109, day: 'Friday' }],
    departmentMap = {};

function mostProfitableDepartment() {
    var currentDep, i;
    for (i = 0; i < salesData.length; i++) {
        currentDep = salesData[i].department;
        if (!departmentMap[currentDep]) {
            departmentMap[currentDep] = 0;
        }
        departmentMap[currentDep] += salesData[i].sales;
    }
}

mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);

console.log(departmentMap);
```

The sam as above with a more concise style with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var salesData = [{ department: 'hardware', sales: 4500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 1500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 5500, day: 'Monday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 7500, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 2505, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 1540, day: 'Tuesday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 1500, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 8507, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 8009, day: 'Wednesday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 12000, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 18007, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 6109, day: 'Thursday' }, { department: 'hardware', sales: 7005, day: 'Friday' }, { department: 'outdoor', sales: 12006, day: 'Friday' }, { department: 'carpentry', sales: 16109, day: 'Friday' }],
    departmentMap = {};

function mostProfitableDepartment() {
    salesData.forEach(function (item) {
        departmentMap[item.department] = (departmentMap[item.department] || 0 ) + item.sales;
    });
}

mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);

console.log(departmentMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want something like this

```
    var departments = [];
    angular.forEach(salesData, function (d) {
        if(departments[d.department]){
            departments[d.department] = departments[d.department] + d.sales;
        }else{
            departments[d.department] = d.sales;
        }
    });
```

in other words you can consider salesData as a json and use foreach to get its values